# PostgreSQL CASE statement requires indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am after some advice please.

I have written a CASE statement to populate a new field. For a database table of over 300 million records this took approx 12 hours.

```
UPDATE line
    SET code = (CASE
        WHEN (group ='{Building}' and term = '{Outline}') then 1
        WHEN (group ='{Building}' and term = '{Division}') then 2
        WHEN (group ='{Building}' and term = '{Partial}') then 3
    ELSE 99           
    END)
    WHERE code is null;
```

What could I do to increase this performance?

Should I add an index to the code column before running the case statement so that it can find records that have a NULL code value quicker.

Or should I create indexes on the columns 'group' and 'term' to help speed it up.

With a table this big it will take a while to create any indexes so it has to balance the time taken to create them and the resulting performance gain.

Thanks for any advice

EDIT
Additional info

Am using PostgreSQL 9.2 64Bit on a Windows 2008 Server
I have used the PostgreSQL Tuning wiki and have optimised the postgresql.conf file
I have done VACUUME and ANALYZE on the table

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions  But an index on `code` will help. If there are relatively few rows where code is null, then maybe even a partial index with the condition `where code is null`

Comment: You can use separate requestes: 

UPDATE line SET code = 1 where group ='{Building}' and term = '{Outline}' and code is null;
UPDATE line SET code = 2 where group ='{Building}' and term = '{Division}' and code is null;
UPDATE line SET code = 3 where group ='{Building}' and term = '{Partial}' and code is null;
UPDATE line SET code = 99 where code is null;
Can you provide EXPLAIN results for each request?

Comment: @VitaliyPro "Update on line  (cost=0.00..48847898.66 rows=41740 width=996)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on line  (cost=0.00..48847898.66 rows=41740 width=996)"
"        Filter: ((code IS NULL) AND (group = '{Building}'::character varying[]) AND (term = '{Outline}'::character varying[])))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index on `code` is not going to help the `case` statement, but it will help the `where`.  There is actually a "give-and-take" on this, because the index needs to be updated as well as the original data.  So, if all the `code` values where `NULL`, an index would not be faster.

An index on `group` and `term` would help *if* you split this into separate updates:

```
UPDATE line
    SET code = 1
    WHERE code is null and group = '{Building}' and term = '{Outline}';
```

Actually, the index that you would want is `line(code, group, term)` for these.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a large number of rows, try:

Edit postgresql.conf and
**increase checkpoint_segments** to 10 or more (>= the space of 300Mio records of your table)
**increase wal_buffers to 16MB** (or greater)

you can also get more performance if you switch
**fsync off**
but, you have a risk to lose data!

an Index on code will speed the update (see doku):
"Also, an IS NULL or IS NOT NULL condition on an index column can be used with a B-tree index."